# Splitting and distributing data from two tables into a new one

Tags: php, mysql

I have been studying and learning PHP and MySQL and I have started a system that I'm developing for a friend's little school and to help me to improve my learning. I basically have in this case a table with the names of the students (tb_std) and another with the names of the teachers (tb_tch). The work is to distribute these students among the teachers in a new table, which is the way I think it will work better (tb_final).

1. I basically need each student to have a randomly chosen teacher so that the distribution is numerically even among the teachers.

In this example, I have 7 teachers and 44 students. Using SELECT query I did the operations to find out how many students would be for each teacher (add/division/mod), but how to make this draw to play in this new table I have no idea where to start.

```
1) Students (tb_std)
    ---------
    id |std
    1  | A1
    2  | A2
    3  | A3
    (...)
    44 | A44
```

```
2) Teachers (tb_tch)
    --------
    id |tch
    --------
    1  | T1
    2  | T2
    3  | T3
    (...)
    7  | T7
```

```
3) Final Combo (tb_final)
    --------------------
    id| student | teacher 
    --------------------
    1 |  A1     | T1   
    2 |  A2     | T2    
    3 |  A3     | T4    
    4 |  A4     | T6    
    5 |  A5     | T2    
    (...)
```

This is what I her in code until now:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");

$str_std="SELECT COUNT(*) as tstd FROM tb_std ";
$qry_std=mysqli_query($conn,$str_std);
while($res1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_std)){
    $v1 = $res1['tstd']; // 44 students
    echo "Students: ".$res1['tstd']."<br>";
}

$str_tch="SELECT COUNT(*) as ttch FROM tb_tch ";
$qry_tch=mysqli_query($conn,$str_tch);
while($res2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_tch)){
    $v2 = $res2['ttch']; // 7 teachers
    echo "Teachers ".$res2['ttch']."<br><br>";
}

$div = number_format($v1 / $v2);
$res = $v1 % $v2;
echo "Stud/Teach: ".$div."<br>"; // 6 std per teach
echo "Mod: ".$res."<br>"; // mod 2

?>
```

I have found some discussions including instructions CREATE and UNION, but I couldn't find other discussions around here that would help me with this division and distribution between tables to generate this new result.

Comment: And what is the exact question? How to split array into parts? `array_chunk` How to insert data into table? `INSERT INTO` query.

Comment: @u_mulder Okay. I think what I need was a little hard to understand. I will edit the question: I basically need each student to have a randomly chosen teacher so that the distribution is numerically even among the teachers. I will study array_chunk. Tks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by next (a bit a complicate) query using window functions:

```sql
    select 
        s.id, std student, tch teacher
    from (
      -- get Students with row_numbers 
      select 
          id,
          row_number() over w as rn,
          std
      from tb_std
      window w as (order by id)
    ) s
    cross join (
        -- get Teachers count and join to each student row
        select count(*) tcnt from tb_tch
    ) tcnt
    join (
      -- select Teachers and join them to students depends row_number
      -- divided to teachers count
      select 
          row_number() over w as trn,
          tch
      from tb_tch
      window w as (order by id)
    ) t on mod(s.rn, tcnt) = t.trn -1;
```

[MySQL 8.0 fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=1b1b61435ad310d8e74a6ba8056fe432&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Result:

```
+====+=========+=========+
| id | student | teacher |
+====+=========+=========+
| 1  | S0      | T2      |
+----+---------+---------+
| 2  | S1      | T3      |
+----+---------+---------+
.........................
+----+---------+---------+
| 20 | S19     | T7      |
+----+---------+---------+
| 21 | S20     | T1      |
+----+---------+---------+
| 22 | S21     | T2      |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Yes @slava-rozhnev, it's a bit complicated, but I can see now where to go and I will study this elements to understand it better. One thing I can't understand is how to insert into tb_final the values form the result shown above. Should I combine this SELECT statement with INSERT INTO, inside the same query, using which variables for id, student and teacher?

Comment: You can use `create table tbl_std_tch as select ...` https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4cc2d26e72d3ddc8bdb7870b3c500a0e&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: That's it, worked fine. Thks a lot for all learning, next I need to find more tutorial and lectures about mysql and sql.

Comment: Mr @slava-rozhnev, just one more question. Everything is working fine, but If it will be hard to explain, don't worry, I will try later. But I was wondering and now trying on SQLize to create 3 teacher columns at tbl_std_tch (teacher, teacher2 e teacher3) for 3 different months, in spite of only one.  I think CROSS JOIN will be the same, but inside JOIN I tried duplicate JOIN as I use INNER JOIN, adding number 2 and 3, but didn't work and I couldn't find some reference.  Could you tell me something more about this? Thks

Comment: This should be asked in separate trade, but you can look here https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=4e2971c78ce9ec07ccadb710f8986e28&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb

Comment: One more question. My localhost run on XAMPP (MariaDB 10.4) and script is adapted and working fine. But I have sent all the files to the server and there MySQL version is Percona 5.6. When I test your script using sqlize.online you posted above, MySQL is version 8.0 and when I try v5.7 I have a message error, the same at Percona. Is there any way to fix the code or just upgrading MySQL on server? Thanks.

Comment: window functions introduced in MySQL since version 8.0 and can not be used in older versions